# UDP conection not working over lan

Tags: java, networking, udp, lan

I have a client and server set up in a project but they are not connecting between computers on my network.

the client:

```
public class GameClient extends Thread {

private static Image image;

private InetAddress ipAddress;
private DatagramSocket socket;
private Play play;

public GameClient(Play play, String ipAddress){
    this.play = play;

    try {
        this.socket = new DatagramSocket();
        this.ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public GameClient(Play play, InetAddress ipAddress){
    this.play = play;

    try {
        this.socket = new DatagramSocket();
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void run() {
    //boolean run = true;
    while(true) {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        try {
            socket.receive(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.parsePacket(packet.getData(), packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());
    }
}

public static void getImage(Image newImage){
    image = newImage;
}

private void parsePacket(byte[] data, InetAddress address, int port) {
    String message = new String(data).trim();
    PacketTypes type = Packet.lookupPacket(message.substring(0, 2));
    Packet packet = null;
    switch (type) {
    default:
    case INVALID:
        break;
    case LOGIN:
       packet = new Packet00Login(data);
       System.out.println("[" + address.getHostAddress() + ":" + port + "] " + ((Packet00Login)packet).getUsername() + " has joined the game");
       PlayerMP player = new PlayerMP(((Packet00Login)packet).getUsername(), (double)200, (double)200, 65, 285, (float)0, (double)1, image, address, port);

       play.addEntity(player);
       play.setClientPlayer(player);
        break;
    case DISCONNECT:
        packet = new Packet01Disconnect(data);
        System.out.println("[" + address.getHostAddress() + ":" + port + "] " + ((Packet01Disconnect)packet).getUsername() + " has left the world...");
        play.removePlayerMP(((Packet01Disconnect)packet).getUsername());
        break;
    case MOVE:
        packet = new Packet02Move(data);
        handleMove((Packet02Move) packet);

    }
}

public void sendData(byte[] data){
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ipAddress, 1331);
    try {
        socket.send(packet);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void handleMove(Packet02Move packet){
    this.play.movePlayer(packet.getUsername(), packet.getX(), packet.getY(), packet.getDirection());
}

}
```

the server:

```
public class GameServer extends Thread {

private static Image image;

private DatagramSocket socket;
private Play play;
private List<PlayerMP> connectedPlayers = new ArrayList<PlayerMP>();

public GameServer(Play play){
    this.play = play;

    try {
        this.socket = new DatagramSocket(1331);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}

public static void getImage(Image newImage){
    image = newImage;
}

public void run() {
    while(true) {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        try {
            socket.receive(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.parsePacket(packet.getData(), packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());
    }
}

private void parsePacket(byte[] data, InetAddress address, int port) {
    String message = new String(data).trim();
    PacketTypes type = Packet.lookupPacket(message.substring(0, 2));
    Packet packet = null;
    switch (type) {
    default:
    case INVALID:
        break;
    case LOGIN:
        packet = new Packet00Login(data);
        System.out.println("[" + address.getHostAddress() + ":" + port + "] " + ((Packet00Login)packet).getUsername() + " has connected to the server...");
        PlayerMP player = new PlayerMP(((Packet00Login)packet).getUsername(), (double)200, (double)200, 65, 285, (float)0, (double)1, image, address, port);
        this.addConnection(player, (Packet00Login)packet);

        break;
    case DISCONNECT:
        packet = new Packet01Disconnect(data);
        System.out.println("[" + address.getHostAddress() + ":" + port + "] " + ((Packet01Disconnect)packet).getUsername() + " has left...");
        this.removeConnection((Packet01Disconnect)packet);
        break;
    case MOVE:
        packet = new Packet02Move(data);
        //System.out.println(((Packet02Move)packet).getUsername() + " has moved to " + (int)((Packet02Move)packet).getX() + " , " + (int)((Packet02Move)packet).getY());
        this.handleMove(((Packet02Move)packet));
        break;
    }
}

public void addConnection(PlayerMP player, Packet00Login packet) {
    boolean alreadyConnected = false;
    if(!this.connectedPlayers.isEmpty()){
        for(PlayerMP p: this.connectedPlayers){
            if(player.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(p.getUsername())){
                System.out.println("Client " + player.getUsername() + " already conected as " + p.getUsername() + ": updating player information");
                if(p.getIpAddress() == null){
                    p.setIpAddress(player.getIpAddress());
                }
                if(p.getPort() == -1){
                    p.setPort(player.getPort());
                }
                alreadyConnected = true;
            }else{
                // relay to the current connected player that there is a new
                // player
                sendData(packet.getData(), p.getIpAddress(), p.getPort());

                // relay to the new player that the currently connect player
                // exists

                packet = new Packet00Login(p.getUsername());
                System.out.println("Sending already conected player to [" + player.getIpAddress().getHostAddress() + ":" + player.getPort() + "] " + player.getUsername());
                sendData(packet.getData(), player.getIpAddress(), player.getPort());
            }
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Sending login to [" + player.getIpAddress().getHostAddress() + ":" + player.getPort() + "] " + player.getUsername());
        sendData(packet.getData(), player.getIpAddress(), player.getPort());
        this.connectedPlayers.add(player);
        alreadyConnected = true;
    }
    if(!alreadyConnected){
        System.out.println("Sending login to [" + player.getIpAddress().getHostAddress() + ":" + player.getPort() + "] " + player.getUsername());
        packet = new Packet00Login(player.getUsername());
        sendData(packet.getData(), player.getIpAddress(), player.getPort());
        this.connectedPlayers.add(player);

    }
}


public void removeConnection(Packet01Disconnect packet) {
    this.connectedPlayers.remove(getPlayerMPIndex(packet.getUsername()));
    packet.writeData(this);
}

public PlayerMP getPlayerMP(String username){
    for(PlayerMP player : this.connectedPlayers){
        return player;
    }
    return null;
}

public int getPlayerMPIndex(String username){
    int index = 0;
    for(PlayerMP player : this.connectedPlayers){
        if(player.getUsername().equals(username)){
            break;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return index;
}

public void sendData(byte[] data, InetAddress ipAddress, int port) {
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ipAddress, port);
    try {
        this.socket.send(packet);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendDataToAllClients(byte[] data) {
    for (PlayerMP p : connectedPlayers) {
        sendData(data, p.getIpAddress(), p.getPort());
    }
}

private void handleMove(Packet02Move packet){
    if(getPlayerMP(packet.getUsername()) != null){
        int index = getPlayerMPIndex(packet.getUsername());
        this.connectedPlayers.get(index).x = packet.getX();
        this.connectedPlayers.get(index).y = packet.getY();
        ((PlayerMP)this.connectedPlayers.get(index)).playerDirection = packet.getDirection();
        packet.writeData(this);
    }
}

}
```

here is where it sends the first login packet to the server from my play class (this packet is not being received)

```
    if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, this, "do you want to start the server?", mousePosX) == 0){
        socketServer = new GameServer(this);
        socketServer.start();
    }
    try {
        socketClient = new GameClient(this, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    socketClient.start();
    GameClient.getImage(standing);// these are just so that the client and the server have the image to create the player entity once they join the game

    GameServer.getImage(standing);
    Packet00Login loginPacket = new Packet00Login(Global.playerUsername);
    loginPacket.writeData(socketClient); //this is where the first login is being sent, it is not being received.
```

To be clear the program works localy on one computer and the ip's look correct (192.0.0.XXX) but when i chose to run the server on one computer and not on the other the second computer does not connect to the first.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried disabling your PC firewall

Comment: @PeterLawrey That didn't work any other ideas?

Comment: How are you configuring your server and your client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, wasent anything to do wit the net work :P turns out i was accidently calling the server directly to send information rather than the client. Moved the server to a new project and set it up as a stand alone as I should have done in the first place and everything works great :). Thanks for the help though!